# What does this line of code do and mean?

Tags: java

```
public class CuteSampleCode
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      CuteSampleCode main = new CuteSampleCode();
   }
}
```

This part:
'CuteSampleCode main = new CuteSampleCode();`
Does it just simplify the class name? So later I can run other methods through it?

Comment: Have a read of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Comment: oh stop with the downvoting and closing as not constructive.  OP is clearly trying to understand a fundamental aspect of Java.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I did not vote, but I think the OP would be better off just picking up and reading a basic tutorial.

Comment: @NPE sure I agree.  However, sometimes giving the quick explanation in human words can be better than a bogged down oracle tutorial.  Granted, I was taught these things at university so my view may be skewed.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - sorry, but I totally disagree. These kinds of questions have no place on this site. Even the most basic of Java tutorials would have covered this.

Comment: Read "Head first core java" ASAP

Comment: @Perception no need to apologize.  Disagreement is what brings about debate :)

Comment: This is really sad. What's so wrong with the question? Anyone new to programming may have a similar question. SO is supposed to give help to people struggling with programming. Sorry but this is laughable.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: It's not even "not constructive"... there's nothing polling, subjective or debatable about this. If people want to vote to close a question, at least pick the right reason...

Comment: @BoltClock indeed mr clock

Comment: @AliAlamiri SO is *not* a tutorial site. *Any* amount of research would have answered this question: this is not an appropriate SO question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does the following things:

1. Allocates space for an Object of type `CuteSampleCode`.
2. Instantiates all default fields of `CuteSampleCode`.
3. Assigns the newly create Object reference to the variable called `main`

Comment: By "instiates all default fields" do you mean "initializes all default fields"?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, too quick with my keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

It creates an instance of the `CuteSampleCode` class.  If the class had any non-static methods you could call them from the `main` variable.

Answer (score 1):

This line instantiates a new object of the class `CuteSampleCode`.

If you know the methods of the class `CuteSampleCode` you could call these methods later with:

```
main.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

This line instantiates a new object of the class CuteSampleCode.And then assign the newly created object